# collectionview within tableview cell doesnt refresh when tableview array is filtered in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two original arrays which the following search bar func filters an array's on Venue.name that matches the search text and reloads the data.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredVenueArray = searchText.isEmpty ? venueArray : venueArray.filter({ (venue: Venue) -> Bool in
        return venue.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    })

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The `filteredVenueArray` array is used to display the list in a `TableView` which also contains a `CollectionView` within each Cell.

The problem is that the `collectionview` data doesnt match the filtered array and therefore images for the corresponding cell Venue do not show.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VenueListingCellImage", for: indexPath) as! VenueListingCellImage

    let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[indexPath.item]

    let imgURL = URL(string: urlString)

    cell.configureCell(url: imgURL!)

    return cell
}
```

EDIT: To include `cellForRowAt`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VenueListingCell", for: indexPath) as? VenueListingCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let venueCurrent = filteredVenueArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.configureCell(venue: venueCurrent) 
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell 

}//end func
```

Comment: Please show how are you connecting the collection view to your table view. I suspect you're not reloading the collection view, only the table view, hence your issue.

Comment: show your `cellForRowAt` implementation for the `tableView`

Comment: collectionView.reloadData() and not tableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `cellForRowAt` method of the tableView do

```
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
return cell
```

Comment: A quick follow up question....how can I ensure that the correct `collectionView` is loaded into the corresponding `tableView` `Cell`?. At times when I pull-down to refresh table, the incorrect collectionView (with images) is being loaded onto the wrong `Cell`?